# Why is this not a linear space of functions?

Tags: analysis, calculus-of-variations

Consider[image]

Why is $D$ not a linear space of functions? It is said that because of the non-zero endpoints, $D$ is not a linear space, because addition is not closed. But I think I'm missing something about this concept. How does one show that $D$ is not closed under addition?

Comment: The space if linear if and only if $\phi_B=\theta_B = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because if $\theta_B\neq 0, (\theta,\phi), \in D, 2\theta(0)=2\theta_B\neq \theta_B$ so $2(\theta,\phi)$ is not in $D$.

Comment: But if $\theta(0)=\theta_B$, why should this imply that $2\theta(0)$ must necessarily be equal to $\theta_B$ in order for $D$ to be closed under addition?

Comment: Because by definition of $D$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a different way to show that $D$ is not linear?